# Accessing Arbitrary nodes from EventHandler target

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling

I'm working on a small JavaFX application. In this application I have the following components :

```
BorderPane -> as the root element
        HBox top, bottom -> top and bottom regions
        VBox left, right -> left and right regions
        FlowPane center -> central region
```

When the central region is clicked i need to access a node in the top region containing some text. In order to access it i climb the graph upwards from the event's target like this :

```
public EventHandler<MouseEvent> fieldClicked = (MouseEvent e) -> {
    FlowPane target = (FlowPane)e.getTarget();
    BorderPane root = (BorderPane)target.getParent();
    HBox top = (HBox)root.getChildren().get(0);
    HBox top_left = (HBox)top.getChildren().get(0);
    Text total = (Text)top_left.getChildren().get(0);
    ObservableList<Node> dices = target.getChildren();
    /* Do some stuff with retrieved nodes */
};
```

Is there a better and less verbose way to access an arbitrary node in the scene graph beside iteratively calling `Node.getParent()`

Comment: why? sounds like a sub-optimal modeling ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not store the field in some other way, no. You may attach some `id` to find a node via CSS selector (`lookup`) but in that case you're better of doing this a different way:

Store the nodes you need to access in fields (or effectively final local variables, if you register event handlers in the same scope where you create the nodes).

```
...
private BorderPane root;
private HBox top;
private Text total;
private FlowPane target;

public EventHandler<MouseEvent> fieldClicked = (MouseEvent e) -> {
    ObservableList<Node> dices = target.getChildren();
    /* Do some stuff with fields */
};

private void initializeNodes() {
    ...
    total = new Text();
    top = new HBox(total);
    root.setTop(top);
    target = new FlowPane();
    root.setCenter(target);
    ...
}
```

It's better to decouple the modification of certain values from the layout of the scene as much as possible anyways, since this makes it easier for you to rearrange the scene without having to worry about event handlers navigating the scene correctly via up-/downward navigation though the scene. Furthermore you'll get into trouble, if you're using your approach in cases where you use a "parent" other than a `Pane` or `Group`, e.g. `ScrollPane` since the skin of `ScrollPane` inserts the `content` node into the scene as it's descendant, but not as it's child and it doesn't do this until the first layout pass.

---

BTW: Note that it's `Event.getSource` that yields the node the event handler was triggered for, not `Event.getTarget`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, straight to the point. I see why I was having troubles, putting every definition in the start() method and forgetting about classe and the possibility of storing entities in their fields.

Answer (score 0):

To get a specific Node, you can use the lookup() method of the  javafx.scene.Scene class.

For Example, you can set an ID on the node containing some text and then find it with scene.lookup("#theID");

```
   public EventHandler<MouseEvent> fieldClicked = (MouseEvent e) -> {
    FlowPane target = (FlowPane)e.getTarget();
    Text total = (Text) target.getScene().lookup("#myTextID");

/* Do some stuff with retrieved nodes */
};
```

The ID you can set by:

```
  Text text = new Text("My Text element somewhere");
  text.setId("myTextID");
```

I'm new to JavaFX so I don't know if this is the best way either. But I hope, this is what you are looking for.

By the way, if you want to get to the root node, you can instead use:

```
   public EventHandler<MouseEvent> fieldClicked = (MouseEvent e) -> {
    FlowPane target = (FlowPane)e.getTarget();
    BorderPane root = (BorderPane) target.getScene().getRoot();

};
```

Its maybe helpful when you have more Elements in your FlowPane, then you also don't have to call that often Node.getParent().

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time, I'll select fabian's answer as its more general. I realize now my approach was wrong and in his answer he tackles the problem, but yes yours would do!